# Python error - list index out of range?

Tags: python

Anyone help me see why I keep getting "list index out of range" as an error ??

```
def printInfo(average):
    average.sort()  # sorts the list of tuples 
    average.reverse()  # reverses the list of tuples 
    print('\tDate\t\tAverage Price')
    for i in range(6):
        print("\t{:.2f}".format(average[i][2], average[i][1], average[i][0]))
```

Comment: You should specify where the error is happening.

Comment: line 40 of my program so it would be the last line above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You hard coded the range of your loop and it is probably greater than the length of the list

A quick fix is

```
def printInfo(average):
    average.sort()  # sorts the list of tuples 
    average.reverse()  # reverses the list of tuples 
    print('\tDate\t\tAverage Price')
    for i in range(len(average)): #Change was here
        print("\t{:.2f}".format(average[i][2], average[i][1], average[i][0]))
```

however, a better fix is to use iteration:

```
def printInfo(average):
    average.sort()  # sorts the list of tuples 
    average.reverse()  # reverses the list of tuples 
    print('\tDate\t\tAverage Price')
    for a in average: # loops through each item of average
        print("\t{:.2f}".format(a[2], a[1], a[0]))
```

Comment: Thanks that fixed my error ! It's not doing what I want completely yet but it's a start so thank you !

Comment: Since this answer fixed your problem, you should click the checkmark below the vote arrows for this answer.  This lets other people know this is the "correct" answer.